# Reading a string from a pointer

Tags: c#, .net

The below code is an example for reading floats, can someone suggest a modification of the function to read a string?

```
   public static float ReadPointerFloat(string EXENAME, int Pointer, int[] Offset)
 {
     float Value = 0;
     checked
     {
         try
         {
             Process[] Proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(EXENAME);
             if (Proc.Length != 0)
             {
                 int Bytes = 0;
                 int Handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, Proc[0].Id);
                 if (Handle != 0)
                 {
                     foreach (int i in Offset)
                     {
                         ReadProcessMemoryInteger((int)Handle, Pointer, ref Pointer, 4, ref Bytes);
                         Pointer += i;
                     }
                     ReadProcessMemoryFloat((int)Handle, Pointer, ref Value, 4, ref Bytes);
                     CloseHandle(Handle);
                 }
             }
         }
         catch
         { }
     }
     return Value;
 }
```

Maybe read a byte array and apply this?

```
ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(variableholdingresultoffunction);
```

Comment: Do you mean a null-terminated string?

Comment: You should not be casting to `int`; your code will not work on x64.  Use `IntPtr`.

Comment: Handles are typically represented using `IntPtr`, not `int`.

Comment: Hi Slaks, There is a maximum character length I found afterall, its up to 16 characters long.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process[] test = Process.GetProcessesByName("myprocess"); //Get process base address
    int Base = test[0].MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32(); // ""


    int Readpointer = ReadPointerInteger("myprocess", Base, new int[3] { 0xC, 0x5, 0x6 });

    string asciiString;
    unsafe
    {
        asciiString = new string((sbyte*)Readpointer);
    }
    // use asciiString
}
```

As others have mentioned, you should use `IntPtr` instead of `int` for your pointers so that it's cross-compatible between 32- and 64-bit systems, but this should get you started.

Comment: I don't understand how to implement this (I didn't vote you down btw)

Comment: Your pointer should be cast to a `char*` or `sbyte*`, depending on what's at the pointer.  Then you call `ReadPointerString(myPointer)` to get the string.  If you need more help, tell me what type(s) your pointer and/or offset and length are, and I'll try to help.

Comment: Ok thanks, well inital problem is that there are a number of offsets to the base pointer as indicated.

Comment: I have dug in and found for at least this example the last pointer in the chain with no offsets, and have changed the code to what you suggested in the trainer class, and called it with: string Readpointer = Trainer.ReadPointerString((char*)0x13056D40); IT gives 1 error: "Pointers and fixed size buffers may only be used in an unsafe context"?

Comment: You need to use `unsafe` to allow pointers.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chfa2zb8(v=vs.71).aspx  After reviewing your original code, I have a better idea of what you're trying to do.  I'll edit my code to have a signature more like your example method.

Comment: Hi, I did that, and checked "allow unsafe code" in properties, but I got this error: "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."